# Multiple optionmenus trace statements in Python tkinter not working

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I have written a Python program for Windows, that displays in a table, the outgoing IP addresses of the device married up with the process, program and other data that is using it.

I am using separate **Listbox** widgets for the IP addresses, processes and programs.

As there is a lot of information in each box, I am trying to have a filter on each listbox so the user can look at specific processes and the IP's they are using.

I have attempted to implement the filters using the **optionmenu** widget. So there is an optionmenu per listbox, and the values in the optionmenu are decided on the output from that listbox. When a value is selected from the optionmenu for that listbox, then that listbox should only display the values selected, along with its corresponding values in the other listboxes.

A part of the code is shown below:

```
def change_dropdown(term, listboxValues):

    fill_in_listboxes.change = True

    deleteListbox()

    change_dropdown.ind_list = getIndex(term, listboxValues)

    #print(change_dropdown.ind_list)

    insert(fill_in_listboxes.processList, processListbox, change_dropdown.ind_list)
    insert(fill_in_listboxes.programList, programListbox, change_dropdown.ind_list)


processVar.trace('w', lambda *args: change_dropdown(processVar.get(), fill_in_listboxes.processList))
programVar.trace('w', lambda *args: change_dropdown(programVar.get(), fill_in_listboxes.programList))
```

The change_dropdown function initially deletes all the values in the listboxes by calling a separate function:

```
deleteListbox()
```

It calls a function that creates a global variable list of numbers that correspond to the indices of the values selected; this is based on the value selected from the optionmenu and checks it against the entire list of values from the listbox:

```
change_dropdown.ind_list = getIndex(term, listboxValues))
```

It then uses the entire set of data per listbox, (which is a global variable created in another function), the listbox object itself, and the index list created above to insert the filtered values data in the listboxes:

```
insert(fill_in_listboxes.processList, processListbox, change_dropdown.ind_list)
insert(fill_in_listboxes.programList, programListbox, change_dropdown.ind_list)
```

When using optionmenus, I am aware that a trace function(?) needs to be created to listen anytime the optionmenu is changed.

I didn't want to create separate functions for each trace call, so I found information from a stackoverflow page that seemed to provide a way to have trace calls for each optionmenu, that called the same function:

```
processVar.trace('w', lambda *args: change_dropdown(processVar.get(), fill_in_listboxes.processList))
programVar.trace('w', lambda *args: change_dropdown(programVar.get(), fill_in_listboxes.programList))
```

Stackoverflow page:

[Getting the choice of optionmenu right after selection Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462654/getting-the-choice-of-optionmenu-right-after-selection-python)

using the answer by Kevin.

This is an image of the first two column boxes without a filter:

[Unfiltered columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJWq6.png)

This is what it looks like when filtered using the first column:

[First column filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CsQp.png)

This is what it looks like when trying to filter on the second column:

[Attempts at filtering on second column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEbhY.png)

I know what is going wrong, but I don't know why. In this line:

```
programVar.trace('w', lambda *args: change_dropdown(programVar.get(), fill_in_listboxes.programList))
```

The second variable relates to all the values found in the **programList** listbox. The list of values related to this listbox is a global variable called **fill_in_listboxes.programList**. However when I checked by using print() commands on the arguments to see what has actually been passed to the change_dropdown function, it actually passed the values from the process Listbox, (**fill_in_listboxes.processList**)

I am confused because when I checked the passed values to the **change_dropdown()** function, the value from the **programVar,get()** is correct, but the **fill_in_listboxes.processList** has been passed as the second argument.

This means when I try to get the indexes of my chosen value from the second listbox, it isn't found because it is trying to find this value from the first listbox!

I believe the problem might have something to do with lambda and closures, but I am not well versed in python enough to understand where I went wrong. I was hoping someone might be able to provide some help.

Comment: Please just include a small [mcve] in the question. Actual code is much easier for us to debug than several dozen paragraphs describing code.

Comment: I have put the relevant code in the question? Not sure whether that’s what you mean

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Did you read the page I linked to?  I mean a small program that we can run to see what you're trying to do. I recommend creating a _new_ small program with perhaps two listboxes and two optionmenus along with some hard-coded data. You don't need much more than that, plus enough code to make it work.

Comment: Apologies I did read it but wasn’t sure that was what you meant. Thank you for clarifying I’ll try and post something tonight

Comment: Even though you say you don't want separate functions for each button, I encourage you to try that approach first. Trying to debug a bunch of code in `lambda` statements is difficult.  Once you get that working you can focus on consolidating them into a single function.

Comment: I did create new functions for each button but this didn't solve the problem; I managed to solve it by looking at the function that was dynamically creating new options in the optionmenu button, see post below.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my own question.

Initially when creating the OptionMenus, I only added one string variable, 'All' as a placeholder.

Subsequently when the corresponding list box was filled with values, the optionmenu associated with that list box was filled with the individual unique values from the list box.

This subsequent population of the optionmenu['menu'] attribute was achieved using the following function:

```
def changeMenu(value, listSet, menuObj):

if not(value in listSet):
    listSet.add(value)
    menuObj.add_command(label=value, command=lambda s=value: processVar.set(s))
```

The 'value' was the individual value that would be added to the optionmenu as taken from the listbox. It was checked against the Python set of already added values for that optionmenu, (argument 'listset') If it didn't exist, then I used the menu widget add_command function to add the value to the list. However in the above code, the function associated with the value, was linked to the var variable, processVar. This corresponded to the processListBox and the option menu associated with the listbox.)

I now think that this meant that whenever the options in the other menus were generated, it would always look at the trace relating to the processVar. Because of this I changed the above code to:

```
def changeMenu(value, listSet, menuObj, varObj):

if not(value in listSet):
    listSet.add(value)
    menuObj.add_command(label=value, command=lambda s=value: varObj.set(s))
```

And when the changeMenu function was called, the varObj argument would relate to the linked var variable for the optionmenu.

Subsequent testing showed the solution worked.